# KAS-ECC OnepassDH using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I'm looking to develop code for KAS-ECC OnepassDH mode using OpenSSL. The logic to do it can be found in [SP-800-56A](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Ar3.pdf). Attached image showing the steps to accomplish this:

[image]

I've tried to do this, shown my steps below:

```
make_peer() {
    peer = EC_POINT_new(group);
    c = BN_CTX_new();
    EC_POINT_set_affine_coordinates_GFp(group, peer, x, y, c);
}

onepassDH() {
                unsigned char Zs[256];
                unsigned char Ze[256];

                // derive private key from input public key
                qsCAVSx = BN_bin2bn(qsCAVSx, qsCAVSxLength, qsCAVSx);
                qsCAVSy = BN_bin2bn(qsCAVSy, qsCAVSyLength, qsCAVSy);
                peerkey = make_peer(group, qsCAVSx, qsCAVSy);
                if(NULL == peerkey)
                   goto fail;

                // Other party key
                ecKey = EC_KEY_new();
                if ( ecKey == NULL  ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("failed to create ecKey\n");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }
                EC_KEY_set_flags(ecKey, EC_FLAG_COFACTOR_ECDH);  

                if ( 0 == EC_KEY_set_group(ecKey, group) ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("cannot set group\n");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                if ( 0 == EC_KEY_generate_key(ecKey) ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("cannot generate key\n");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                //extract public key from other party's key pair

                ec_ctx = BN_CTX_new();
                if ( !ec_ctx ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("BN_CTX_new() returned NULL in %s at line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }
                qeIUTx = BN_CTX_get(ec_ctx);
                qeIUTy = BN_CTX_get(ec_ctx);
                if ( !qeIUTx || !qeIUTy ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("BN_CTX_get() returned NULL in %s at line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                grp = EC_KEY_get0_group(ecKey);
                if ( grp == NULL ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("EC_KEY_get0_group() returned NULL!");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                pt = EC_KEY_get0_public_key(ecKey);
                if ( pt == NULL ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("EC_KEY_get0_public_key() returned NULL!");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                meth = EC_GROUP_method_of(grp);
                if ( meth == NULL ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("EC_GROUP_method_of() returned NULL\n");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                // this uses "grp", "pt", and "ctx" to set "tx" and "ty"
                EC_POINT_get_affine_coordinates_GFp(grp, pt, qeIUTx, qeIUTy, ec_ctx);


                qeIUTxLength  = BN_num_bytes(qeIUTx);

                qeIUTyLength  = BN_num_bytes(qeIUTy);

                zLength = (EC_GROUP_get_degree(group) + 7)/8;

                ECDH_compute_key(Zs, zLength, peerkey, ecKey, 0);

                // Generate ephemeral key
                de_Key = EC_KEY_new();
                if ( de_Key == NULL  ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("failed to create ecKey\n");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }
                EC_KEY_set_flags(de_Key, EC_FLAG_COFACTOR_ECDH);  // <--- this is the FIPS-dependant part

                if ( 0 == EC_KEY_set_group(de_Key, group) ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("cannot set group\n");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                if ( 0 == EC_KEY_generate_key(de_Key) ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("cannot generate key\n");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                ec_ctx = BN_CTX_new();
                if ( !ec_ctx ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("BN_CTX_new() returned NULL in %s at line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }
                qeIUTx = BN_CTX_get(ec_ctx);
                qeIUTy = BN_CTX_get(ec_ctx);
                if ( !qeIUTx || !qeIUTy ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("BN_CTX_get() returned NULL in %s at line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                grp = EC_KEY_get0_group(de_Key);
                if ( grp == NULL ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("EC_KEY_get0_group() returned NULL!");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                pt = EC_KEY_get0_public_key(de_Key);
                if ( pt == NULL ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("EC_KEY_get0_public_key() returned NULL!");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                meth = EC_GROUP_method_of(grp);
                if ( meth == NULL ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("EC_GROUP_method_of() returned NULL\n");
                   LOG_ERROR("OpenSSL reports:   %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
                   goto fail;
                }

                // this uses "grp", "pt", and "ctx" to set "tx" and "ty"
                EC_POINT_get_affine_coordinates_GFp(grp, pt, qeIUTx, qeIUTy, ec_ctx);
                ECDH_compute_key(Ze, zLength, de_priv_key, ecKey, 0);

                zLength = 2 * ((EC_GROUP_get_degree(group) + 7)/8);
                memcpy(Z, Ze, zLength/2);
                memcpy(Z+(zLength/2), Zs, zLength/2);

                ECDH_compute_key(Z, zLength, peerkey, ecKey, 0);
                // Hash the sharesecret
                ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
                if ( 0 == EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx, md, NULL) ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("error in %s, line%d; sha_type %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, md->md_size * 8);
                   ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
                   goto fail;
                }
                if ( 0 == EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, Z, zLength) ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("error in %s, line%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
                   ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
                   goto fail;
                }
                if ( 0 == EVP_DigestFinal_ex(ctx, iutTag, &count) ) {
                   LOG_ERROR("error in %s, line%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
                   ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
                   goto fail;
                }
        }
}
```

The input for this test is :

```
[EC - SHA256]

COUNT = 0
QsCAVSx = f49fdbdc47a34d17005690ff1d66cdc6862276fdf819a1da3595b0d5e04ecbba
QsCAVSy = 4e182b6e7a644adab028ad089273eb72ac8c2b3834f80b198882bab53c9f856d
```

Problem with KAS-ECC alg is that I don't see much help online to implement this. I found a couple of links: [link1](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Key_Agreement), [link2](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie_Hellman) but didn't help me much with writing code for OnePassDH. Is there anyone who can tell me what seems to be wrong with my code? Right now the code itself does not throw an error but then gives the same result for any input.

Answer (score 2):

**Summary**

I've managed to implement ECDH via OpenSSL and use [CAVP](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/cryptographic-algorithm-validation-program/Component-Testing) test vectors for testing. I hope this answer will help.

---

**Algorithm description**

Note: pseudocode below is just a path to follow, because it is simplified from a more complex system. There will be no many exact types mentioned or error checks done.

Summary: create EC_GROUP from curve, create EC_KEY, EVP_PKEY structures from byte arrays for both public and private keys, create EVP_PKEY_CONTEXT for DH operation, derive key.

1. Create EC_GROUP by curve name:

   ```
   auto order = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_curve)
   ```
2. Create private key (this is just a random number):

   ```
   auto prvKey = BN_new();
   auto order = BN_new();
   EC_GROUP_get_order(group, order, nullptr);
   BN_rand_range(prvKey, order);
   ```
3. Obtain other's party public key:

   ```
   std::vector<uint8_t> otherKey = getOtherKey();
   ```
4. Create and init context:

   ```
   //Create EC_KEY
   auto key = EC_KEY_new();
   EC_KEY_set_group(key, group);
   ECDSA_set_method(key, ECDSA_get_default_method());
   EC_KEY_set_private_key(key, prvKey);

   //Create EVP_PKEY and set EC_KEY there
   auto pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
   EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY(pkey, key);

   //Create EVP_PKEY for public key:
   auto publicEcKey = EC_KEY_new();
   EC_KEY_set_group(publicEcKey, group);
   ECDSA_set_method(publicEcKey, ECDSA_get_default_method());
   EC_POINT point = EC_POINT_new(group);
   EC_POINT_oct2point(group, point, otherKey.data(), otherKey.size());
   EC_KEY_set_public_key(publicEcKey, point);
   auto publicEvpPkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
   EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY(publicEvpPkey, publicEcKey);


   //Create EVP_PKEY_CTX
   auto pkeyCtx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, nullptr);
   EVP_PKEY_derive_init(pkeyCtx);
   ```
5. Derive secret:

   ```
   EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer(pkeyCtx, publicEvpPkey);
   size_t length = 0;
   EVP_PKEY_derive(pkeyCtx, nullptr, &length);
   std::vector<uint8_t> secret(length);
   EVP_PKEY_derive(pkeyCtx, secret.data(), &length);
   ```

---

**How to use CAVP test vectors**
Sample looks like:

```
[P-192]

COUNT = 0
QCAVSx = 42ea6dd9969dd2a61fea1aac7f8e98edcc896c6e55857cc0
QCAVSy = dfbe5d7c61fac88b11811bde328e8a0d12bf01a9d204b523
dIUT = f17d3fea367b74d340851ca4270dcb24c271f445bed9d527
QIUTx = b15053401f57285637ec324c1cd2139e3a67de3739234b37
QIUTy = f269c158637482aad644cd692dd1d3ef2c8a7c49e389f7f6
ZIUT = 803d8ab2e5b6e6fca715737c3a82f7ce3c783124f6d51cd0
```

Here [QCAVSx, QCAVSy] and [QIUTx, QIUTy] - are public vectors for CAVS(distant user) and IUT(user) respectively. In order to use this data as public key for OpenSSL, I created uncompressed form from both coordinates via concatenating them and adding "04" at the beginning (04 is a mark of uncompressed form): 04[x-coordinate][y-ccordinate].
dIUT is a private key for IUT. 
ZIUT is a secret which is the reference result.

I've treated dIUT and uncompressed QCAVS public key as byte arrays to use with OpenSSL via BN_bin2bn() function, and with the help of algorithm above my tests were successful.